# iOS opendir("/Library") Operation not permitted

Tags: ios, posix-api

The permission of the directories as follows:

```
/Applications d rwxrwxr-x root admin
/Library      d rwxrwxr-x root admin
/private      d rwxr-xr-x root wheel
```

`opendir("/Applications")`  it works well
`opendir("/Library")`  Operation not permitted
`opendir("/private")`  Operation not permitted

Runtime environment:
iOS devices 7.7/9.2 + xcode 7.2
and the debug msg use `print()` to print in the console
but it works well when using iOS Simulators instead of iOS devices

i try to get *user* and *group* of the thread, by using `getpwuid(getuid())` and `getgrgid(getgid())`, it told the result of *mobile* and *mobile*

```
void RootPremission::getDirFiles (const char* path, int deep) { // outside call this function with parameter "/" and 0
    struct stat statBuf;
    if (lstat(path, &statBuf) == 0) {
        printf("%s\n", setFileInfo(&statBuf));

        if (S_ISDIR(statBuf.st_mode)) { // go deep dir
            DIR *dp = NULL;
            if ((dp = opendir(path)) != NULL) {
                struct dirent *dirp = NULL;
                while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
                    if (strcmp(dirp->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dirp->d_name, "..") == 0 || *dirp->d_name == '.') {
                        continue;   // ignore . and .. and hiden file
                    }

                    for (int i=0; i!=deep; ++i) {
                        printf(" ");
                    }
                    printf("|- %s ", dirp->d_name);

                    char *fullPath = strcatPath(path, dirp->d_name);
                    getDirFiles (fullPath, deep+1);
                    free(fullPath);
                    fullPath = NULL;
                }
                closedir(dp);
            }
            else {
                printf("#");
                perror(path);
            }
        }
        else {  // try to open file
            if (S_ISREG(statBuf.st_mode)) {
                FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");
                if (file != NULL) {
                    if (fclose(file) == EOF) {
                        perror(path);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    printf("+");
                    perror(path);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("$");
        perror(path);
    }
}
```

The problem is : 
*1. with **using the iOS device, the same permission, the same user and the same group**, why "/Applications" can work well and "/Library" work with the Operation not permitted ???*
*2. when **using iOS Simulators instead of iOS devices**, these three directories can open by using `opendir()` ???*

thank you for your kindness !!!

Comment: The iOS sandbox limits where you can read. The sandbox is not enforced on the simulator.

Comment: thanks for your help, as you mention **snadbox**, do you mean `opendir()` is not a posix-api , but most like a function implementations by the iOS system itsellf, and there is not way to use the posix-api correctly on iOS platform if **snadbox** is there ?

Comment: You can use opendir() on iOS but you must ensure that the path you are trying to read is in your application's sandbox - see NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains